# The comparison of certain modules arising from the Cauchy-Riemann differential operator

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, differential-operators, hochschild-cohomology

Let  $\Gamma=C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ be the space of all smooth complex valued functions on the plane. We define  the  following  Cauchy Riemann  differential operator $D$ on $\Gamma$:

$$D:\Gamma \to \Gamma\\D(u+iv)=(u_x-v_y)+i(u_y+v_x)$$

We put  $$M_k=\ker D^k$$

Then $M_1$ is the  algebra of entire holomorphic  functions  and each  $M_k$ is  a  module on $M_1$.

Let $A_n$  be  the  space of  all  complex  continuous  functions $f$ on $\bar{\mathbb{D}}=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid |z|\leq1 \}$  such that the restriction of  $f$ to the interior $\mathbb{D}$ of $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ lies in $\ker D^n$. Then $A_1$ is the  standard Disc algebra  and each $A_k$ is  an $A_1$-module.

Obviously $M=\cup M_i$ and  $A=\cup A_i$  are  algebra  of  functions.(closed  under multiplication).

> Assume that  $f\in A$ ($f\in M$) is  non vanishing. Does $1/f$ necessarily belong to $A$ (belong to $M$)?

Obviously $M\subset C^{\omega}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, the space  of real  analytic complex valued functions on the plane.

> Is it true to say that each element of $M$ has a global convergence  Taylor  series around the origin ?
>
> What can be  said  about the purely algebraic  module  structures of  $A_k$'s?Are they  finitely generated projective module? Is it true to say that $A_k$ is not isomorphic to $A_{k'}$  for  $k\neq k'$?We have the same question when $A_k$  is  considered as an Banach  $A_1$-module.
>
> What is the  Hocschild  cohomology of  $A_1$  with  coefficient in $A_k$?(Where $A_k$ is  considered as a Banach $A_1$ module)
>
> For  a  complex  manifold $N$, is  there an appropriate analogy of  $M_k,s$? If yes, what invariants  of these $M_1$ modules $M_k$ have non trivial interpretations in terms of complex structure of $N$?